# Tools for Managing Bankroll, Income and Losses

Tags: bankroll, bankroll-management, poker-tools, session-accounting

What professional grade tools available for managing a poker bankroll, and trending income and losses?

Web, desktop, and phone applications are all welcome.

Comment: online or offline or both?  Poker income or non-poker income?

Comment: Both are welcome

Comment: Can we get more specific information on what "managing a poker bankroll" means? You want to take $100 and turn it into $10,000 sort of  bankroll challenge, or are you are starting out and looking for a first deposit amount on some particular site?
Also, how much one is willing to spend would influence potential answers.

If you just want to track every stat you can think of, Toby nailed it, PT and HM are some professional masterpieces of poker software.

Answer (score 8):

The two most well known database management tools are [PokerTracker](http://www.pokertracker.com/) (I have this one) and [Holdem Manager](http://www.holdemmanager.com/).

Both are very good, but I prefer PT's extensibilty using PostgreSQL.

Also, [evplusplus](http://www.evplusplus.com/) have other useful things, like a [Risk of Ruin](http://www.evplusplus.com/poker_tools/risk_of_ruin/) calculator, [Winrate Confidence](http://www.evplusplus.com/poker_tools/poker_winrate_confidence/) calculator and [bankroll management](http://www.evplusplus.com/poker_tools/bankroll_simulator/) simulator that I've used extensively to model how I manage my money.

I've also used them to simulate other volatility scenarios on horse racing and sports betting that I use in my other gambling pursuits. It's very adaptable.

Answer (score 5):

If you know your winrate and your standard deviation information you should be able to estimate your bankroll requirements by looking at the ev++ variance calculator. You'll see a good amount of information here about longest breakeven and downswings and other winrate related estimates:
http://www.evplusplus.com/poker_tools/variance_simulator/

For tournaments you may want to look at this blog post:
http://www.nsdpoker.com/2011/01/mtt-pros/

Answer (score 0):

[Neverbust](https://www.neverbust.com) can give you a lot of information to manage your poker bankroll, including:

- *Hourly*: How much you win, on average, per hour
- *Standard deviation*: How wide your swings are
- *Margin of error*: How much you can expect your hourly to deviate from your true hourly
- *Risk of ruin*: The odds of your bankroll going to zero
- *Bankroll requirements*: The amount of money you need in your bankroll

Full disclosure: I am the creator of Neverbust.