# Total Money vs Money Invested In Current Game

Tags: terminology, bankroll-management

What are the correct poker terms for

1. total money that you have, combining all the money from all the tables plus any and all money you don't have invested on any table
2. money invested on current table(s) that you are playing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't think these are solely poker terms,

1. "Total Money" is equivalent to **Bankroll**.
2. "Money Invested" is equivalent to **Money at Risk** or **Current Exposure to Risk**.

Some useful links to answers from this site on the topic of bankroll are:

- [What is a proper starting bankroll?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/718/what-is-a-proper-starting-bankroll/720#720)
- [Tools for Managing Bankroll, Income and Losses](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/85/tools-for-managing-bankroll-income-and-losses/101#101)